# Using JSON from a web API

Tags: html, json, ajax

I am trying to take data from a game and display it on a web page as soon as the web page is loaded.
This is my script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#csgoStat").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=12A1D1DE83F9932934EDD6DF2BA00463&steamid=76561198010352479",
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(output) {
                    document.getElementById(""total_kills).innerHTML = output.totalKills;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

This is an example of the JSON data from the link above

```
{"playerstats":{"steamID":"76561198010352479","gameName":"ValveTestApp260","stats":[{"name":"total_kills","value":18823},{"name":"total_deaths","value":17093},{"name":"total_time_played","value":1591942}]}}
```

This is my code in the body of my HTML file

```
    <div class="split left">
    <div class="centered">
        <h2>#Username Statistics</h2>
        <img src="myAvatar%20(1).png">

        <p id="totalKills">total kills</p>
        <p id="totalDeaths">total kills</p>
        <p id="totalTimePlayed">total kills</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what my page looks like.

[image: section of the webpage]

I am probably missing loads of code and I've been trying to figure it out plus look for tutorials, but I'm struggling to understand, I am a bit of a novice.

Thank you

Comment: The first thing you would need to identify is the way in which the code may be failing.  Open your browser's debugging tools.  Check for any errors on the Console tab (there's a syntax error in your code, so that's likely reported in the console), observe the AJAX request and response in the Network tab, use the Script debugger to step through the code as needed for debugging, etc.  (At a glance, the HTML in the question doesn't even have the `#csgoStat` element that you intend to click on...)

Comment: I have introduced a button like so 

            <button type="button" id="csgoStat">Press</button>

Comment: `(""total_kills)` should be `("totalKills")`

Answer (score -1):

Basically you will have to do something like this for each value you want to display (within the "success" function):

```
document.getElementById("totalKills").innerHTML = 
   output.playerstats.stats.filter(x => x.name === "total_kills")[0].value;
```

This should work for multiple properties at once:

```
[  /* ID */            /* stat property name from the response data */
  ["totalKills",       "total_kills"],
  ["totalDeaths",      "total_deaths"],
  ["totalTimePlayed",  "total_time_played"],
].forEach(e => document.getElementById(e[0]).innerHTML = 
     output.playerstats.stats.filter(s => s.name === e[1])[0].value;
);
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#csgoStat").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=12A1D1DE83F9932934EDD6DF2BA00463&steamid=76561198010352479",
      type: "GET",
      success: function (output) {
        [
          ["totalKills", "total_kills"],
          ["totalDeaths", "total_deaths"],
          ["totalTimePlayed", "total_time_played"]
        ].forEach(e =>
            document.getElementById(e[0]).innerHTML = 
                output.playerstats.stats.filter(s => s.name === e[1])[0].value
        );
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="totalKills">total kills</p>
<p id="totalDeaths">total deaths</p>
<p id="totalTimePlayed">total time played</p>

<button id="csgoStat">LOAD STATS</button>
```